# Roles asp.net settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently developing an app with `ASP.NET MVC 4`, but I`am also learning.

I want to use Roles, for authentication, but something I`am doing wrong.

The point is that I dont need more roles, I just want the default one.

```
<system.web>

<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<roleManager enabled="true" />
```

At controller

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{}
```

And in the LogIn post method I want to add user to that role.

```
if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(saveAccount.Username, "Administrators"))
     Roles.AddUserToRole(saveAccount.Username, "Administrators");
```

But everytime I LogIn and try to redirect to another page I get this

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

Can someone guide me, please?

Comment: Can you confirm if the user is assigned to Administrators role in database?

Comment: I don't have a database for roles, its a must? Because I just want to limit acces to registered users. The point is that I have only one type of users...

Comment: You have to somehow assign a user to one or more roles, and I'm hard pressed to see how you'd do that without persisting the roles and their assignments in a database. Regardless, the error is explicit. The user is *not* in the indicated role and is therefore unauthorized (401).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roles is Authorization, Authentication is another process.

If your need is just to restrict on known users, then :

- Create a login view with user/pass
- Implemente Forms authentication on web.config section `<system.web>`
- Deny anonymous users

.

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
             <forms all parameters needed to a connection's forms></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what  I need.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a user to a role, you have to use the UserId, not the username.

You also have to create a record in the Roles table with the name of the role you desire.

Use RoleManager to create a new role.

```
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));

        if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
        {

            //Creating Admin role  
            var role = new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole();
            role.Name = "Administrator";
            roleManager.Create(role);
        }

        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole(#yourUserId, "Administrator")) {
            Roles.AddUserToRole(#yourUserId, "Administrator");
        }
```

(The database for your users and roles is under DefaultConnection in the Data Connections area within Server Explorer).

Comment: Replace '#yourUserId' with the UserId in your program.